# Is possible to manage computing power on Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm new to Google Earth Engine and I can't modify or choose the computing power like the Compute Engine service on Google Cloud Platform.
It's this possible! Thanks!

Comment: Not that I'm aware of no. But there could be interesting ways to decrease the computational power of your analysis. Any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, no. Earth Engine is a shared service — your computation runs on the same machines as everyone else's.

Your main choice is between whether you use the interactive API with things like `print`, `evaluate`, interactive maps, etc. or whether you use [exports](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/exporting) which can run for much longer times and with more resources. But your first step should always be to ensure that your code is written to run efficiently and makes use of Earth Engine's strengths.